# tab panel like stackoverflow

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs

i am wondering from last 2 days, how to implement a tab pannel like stackoverflow eg. https://stackoverflow.com/ (tag question pannel: interesting,feature,hot....)

I am a  server-side developer(Java), i have no experience with web design. But currently , i need this type of tab panel for my personal works.

I tried to search in google but i could not found similar to stackoverflow.com. Though i found   [this tab pannel](http://squaredcode.comoj.com/)  ,but i don't know how to get its source code.

Please help,if you know similar link with source code or you have any suggestions

Comment: Right click > Soure/Inspect Element(For Opera)

Comment: http://hanshillen.github.io/jqtest/#goto_tabs

Comment: @FelipeAls Thank you. I know those but i am looking for specific like stackoverflow.com or similar like http://squaredcode.comoj.com/   . These tabs are very fine. If know links or suggestion then please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some options for you:

- http://jqueryui.com/tabs/
- http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs
- http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/

They are all open source and easy to download. They all come with example code.

They are all customizable for styling too.

Here is an example using easytabs with styling such as you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hh95r/

Take particular note of the css for `.tabs` and `.tabs:hover` as that is what adds the border.

Comment: Thank you. I know those but i am looking for specific like stackoverflow.com or similar like http://squaredcode.comoj.com/   . These tabs are very fine. If know links or suggestion then please help.

Comment: What do you mean 'like stackoverflow'? What exactly about the stackoverflow tabs is different/do you need? Most of the examples above can be styled differently and have content dynamically loaded (with a little work). They are flexible. Please add to your question specifically what your requirements are.

Comment: if i click this(http://stackoverflow.com/) link, i see the tab-pannel including these data->> `Top Questions: interesting | featured | hot | week | month`           I think now you know my exact requirement?

Comment: No, I don't. Is it the styling? Or the content? Or is it the functionality?

Comment: styling, i am looking for tab pannel styling

Comment: Have added a link to example with styling.

Comment: this is fine, but one doubt. While hover, can you remove bottom border of tab?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Hh95r/5/